# How do I open a file with only the FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES permission?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to issue a [FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364569(v=vs.85).aspx) control code from a non administrator program. The doc says "Either FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES access is sufficient when opening the volume" so I believe that this should be possible. I tried both the path and the volume path: "\.\C:" "\?\Volume{4f26a671-c36e-11e2-913d-806e6f6e6963}" and while I can open them both the call to DeviceIOControl will only work with `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`. Here is the code:

```
int main(){
    char *mount = "\\\\.\\C:";
    HANDLE hHandle = CreateFile(mount
                                    , FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                    , FILE_SHARE_READ
                                    , NULL
                                    , OPEN_EXISTING
                                    , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
                                    , NULL);
                                    //*/
    if (hHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        DWORD dwBytesReturned;
        NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER volume_data;
        int bResult = DeviceIoControl(hHandle
                                        , FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA
                                        , NULL
                                        , 0
                                        , &volume_data
                                        , sizeof(volume_data)
                                        , &dwBytesReturned
                                        , NULL);
        if (bResult){
            printf("Success!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Last Error = %d (%s)\n", GetLastError(), mount);
        }
        CloseHandle(hHandle);
    } else {
        printf("Error invalid handle: %s\n", mount);
    }
}
```

Last Error prints out 1, btw.

Comment: Please remove FILE_SHARE_WRITE flag.

Comment: try using the another volume name instead of C

Comment: Unfortunately I only have one drive/volume. I have tried `\\?\Volume{4f26a671-c36e-11e2-913d-806e6f6e6963}` as well, and that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system, `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` does not work, but `FILE_EXECUTE` does and can be used without admin privilege.

I did also need to change the sharing options to

```
FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE
```

to get it to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the macro GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE instead of FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES.Please go through the documentation of dwDesiredAccess and dwFlagsAndAttributes parameters of the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. I think you misunderstand these two parameters.

Comment: GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE requires administrative access, that was the problem with the question to begin with :(